# Get list of subscription apps by user from google play

Tags: android, google-api, google-console-developer

I want subscription list of app in android which is subscribed by user. I want to create app of get subscription list and it will notify to user your "xyz app" subscription is going to expire/renew by "for example date (10-9-2018)"

Comment: Hello, your question is too broad please narrow it down.

Comment: Actually I want all subscribed app list from google